# datatable jquery Cannot reinitialise DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I am using datatable jQuery plugin to populate data to table. I need to get data from ajax call when user press button and populate the data to table.

My ajax call code is this:

```
function getJsonReport() {
            var startDate = $('#start_date').val();
            var endDate = $('#end_date').val();
            $.get('MonthlyReportAjax', {startDate : startDate , endDate : endDate}, function(responseText) {               

                var tableBody="";
                for(var x = 0 ; x < responseText["monthRecord"].length ; x++){
                    tableBody += "<tr><td>"+ responseText["monthRecord"][x].date +"</td>"+
                                      "<td>"+ responseText["monthRecord"][x].newSearch +"</td>"+
                                      "<td>"+ responseText["monthRecord"][x].newSubscribers +"</td>"+
                                      "<td>"+ responseText["monthRecord"][x].pm12 +"</td>"+
                                      "<td>"+ responseText["monthRecord"][x].pm3 +"</td>"+
                                      "<td>"+ responseText["monthRecord"][x].pm6 +"</td>"+
                                      "<td>"+ responseText["monthRecord"][x].newAdds +"</td>"+
                                   "</tr>"
                }

                $('#dailyTableBody').html(tableBody);
                $('#tableID').DataTable();
            });
        }
```

first time it works fine, but if user again press button it gives error saying:

> Cannot reinitialise DataTable.
>
> To retrieve the DataTables object for this table, pass no arguments or see the docs for bRetrieve and bDestroy

Comment: I can provide an example usage scenario, but the usage will require you create the HTML table when the page is rendered, and run the AJAX call through DataTables. It will also use alot more of the DataTable options. Unfortunately I am away from my desk, but I will provide it here sometime tomorrow.

Comment: oK THANK you. I will wait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to keep the existing implementation the following will work. The problem you are encountering is as the error message states: You can not initialize a new `DataTable` where one already exists so you have to destroy it and re-create it similar to the below.

DataTables [Destroy](http://datatables.net/reference/api/destroy%28%29) API call is what you are needing.

**Example (untested)**:

```
$('#submit').on( 'click', function () {
    var table = $('#myTable').dataTable() || false;
    if (table) {
        table.api().destroy();
    }
    getJsonReport(); // Run your update function
});
```

**NOTE** The `dataTable` part. This syntax is required on the call to `api()`.

Your `getJsonReport()` function will remain the same. I would actually use a different design model on the DataTable that self-contains all the logic for the DataTable and then uses the API exclusively do do any updated. This requires a refactor to how the table is generated so I did not want to include it, but if you want to see my approach to datatables (I have had to use this library for years at work, till we went Angular ;)) and I will be happy to provide it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: we need to destroy the table before reinitialize it? Another problem is when first time load the table it does not paging correctly. So howw to do that?

Comment: can you provide me your approach for datatable. Sample codes?

Comment: You are creating table with strings then using DataTable.  You should just pass the data to the datatable and liet it do the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

The code below is untested but it should show you what I am suggesting in my comment above and will take a little adjustment to work for you.  It lets DataTable do all of the heaving lifting.
It replaces getJsonReport, initializes on load and uses a go button to initiate a data fetch.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
        $("#tableID").DataTable({columns:[{data:"date"}, {data:"newSearch"}, {data:"newSubscribers"}, {data:"pm12"}, {data:"pm3"}, {data:"pm6"}, {data:"newAdds"}],
            deferLoading:0,
            dom""Bt",
            serverSide:true,

            buttons:[{text:"Go", action: function(){
                $("#tableID").DataTable().ajax.reload();
            }}],
            ajax: {type:"get",
                dataSrc:"",
                url:'MonthlyReportAjax',
                data: function () {return {startDate : $('#start_date').val() , endDate : $('#end_date').val()}
                } 
            }
        });

})
```

Answer (score 0):

In java script put this code...

```
 $('#idTable').dataTable({
     destroy: true
      });
```